# How to read multiple packages using a for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

This is my code:

```
library(gcookbook)
library(ggplot2)
```

I'd like to achieve something like the following:

```
packages <- c("gcookbook","ggplot2") 
for (i in length(packages)) { 
  library(packages[i]) 
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a loop you can use the lapply function like this:

```
packages <- c("gcookbook", "ggplot2")
lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please show me the for loop version?